# How to put system icons in menus?

Tags: c++, qt, ubuntu, qt5, qicon

I have run the menu example from Qt and there are no icons on menus, only text. Most apps (like pcmanfm and caja from Ubuntu) have similar icons, so I suppose they are system-wide and not application specific. How could I put icons in menu items? A code sample would be interesting.

Answer (score 8, accepted):

To obtain the icons of the systems you must use the method [`QIcon::fromTheme()`](http://doc.qt.io/qt-5/qicon.html#fromTheme)

Example:

```
newAct = new QAction(tr("&New"), this);
newAct->setIcon(QIcon::fromTheme("document-new"));
```

Qt uses as a backend to freedesktop icon, it has a rule in the names, the updated list of them can be found in the following [link](https://specifications.freedesktop.org/icon-naming-spec/icon-naming-spec-latest.html)

Answer (score 2):

The `QIcon::fromTheme()` function found in the other answer is unfortunately not portable to Mac or windows. You may have better luck using [`QStyle::standardIcon()`](https://doc.qt.io/qt-5/qstyle.html#standardIcon).